# Problem in Launching Gazebo using bot_launch.py file in launch file

Tags: slam, simulation, gazebo, ros2

hello good day i experience error on running a launch file in ros2. The file is use to launch gazebo empty world. I'm new in ROS2 i still confuse on how to create workspaces and etc.  can you recommend some documentation on how to create a launch file for custom world which the file type is STL.

```
ros2 launch robot_gazebo bot_launch.py
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/dianne/.ros/log/2023-07-08-18-16-28-160996-dianne-47206
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): Caught exception when trying to load file of format [py]: "package 'robot-gazebo' not found, searching: ['/home/dianne/robot_wp/install/robot_gazebo', '/home/dianne/robot_wp/install/robot_description', '/opt/ros/humble']"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix map launch file is not found in directory and also caught exception in launch](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/24978/how-to-fix-map-launch-file-is-not-found-in-directory-and-also-caught-exception-i). This seems to be a duplicate of your earlier question. If it is, please edit the previous question, rather than posting a new one. If it isn't, please [edit] and explain why it is different.